# How to add a php to a custom page

Tags: javascript

Here is what I am trying to do, I have a bookmarklet with the following code

```
javascript:location.href="http://mywebsite.com/getsource?url="+encodeURIComponent(location.href);
```

I want to fill in the url into a field on the page "http://mywebsite.com/getsource"

After asking around a bit, I was provided this piece of code.

```
<input type="text" id="edit-url-field" value="<?php echo $_GET['url']; ?>" />
```

My question is .. how do I implement this in Drupal 7?

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement a custom module which defines a form and a path to this form.

In Drupal forms are implemented with the Form API. Please check this links for more information

1. http://drupal.org/node/751826
2. http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7

You can define the path by implementing [hook_menu](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7).

Comment: I guess you meant _path_, not _bath_. `;)`

Comment: So how do you make it the default value ?
`'#default_value' => !empty($_GET['url']) ? $_GET['url'] : ''`